# Xamarin Forms button with loading indicator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm into Xamarin since about week and have a question about the possibility of making loading icon inside a button.

I would like to achieve something similiar to this:
https://jsfiddle.net/mr8fwtcv/

I was trying to achieve this effect with FontAwesome but had a problem animating it, so it would be not bad to use Activity Indicator in the solution.

My button is placed inside Stack Layout, and here is the code:

```
var loginButton = new Button
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("689F38"),
    TextColor = Color.White,
    HeightRequest = 46,
    Text = "Log in",
    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
    FontSize = 18,
    Margin = margin
};
```

I was already looking for some plugins / solutions but couldn't find any.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try just adding an [`ActivityIndicator`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/) on top of the button and setting the `Text` Property of the `Button` to an empty string once `IsBusy` (or whatever you bind to) is `true`?

Comment: I would do what Demitrian has recommended or create a ButtonRemderer and add it to the native. In the OpropretyChanging override, you can handle the functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to use a Layout to have more than one control in it. If you are not looking for CustomRenderers then what you could do is have a RelativeLayout and inside that both the Button and the Activity Indicator. You will also have to write a Converter for the button text that will set the text to string.Empty when the IsBusy is true.

For example:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
    <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText, Converter={StaticResource ButtonTextConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding IsBusy}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Also if you are planning to use this in multiple places you can create this as a custom control.

You can check out the custom control code [here](https://github.com/rohitvipin/Xamarin-Forms-CustomControls/blob/master/CustomControls/Controls/ButtonWithBusyIndicator.cs).

The full project is available [here](https://github.com/rohitvipin/Xamarin-Forms-CustomControls).